# How to get latest stable Ruby version from command line?

Tags: ruby, shell, terminal, version, command-line-interface

I'm interested in querying the **latest stable version** of Ruby from the command line. I'm primarily interested in a **string of the form "1.9.3p327"**.

**Update #1**

To clarify, the goal is to consistently query the **latest stable version**, whether that be 1.9.3p327 or 3.0.2p392.

Comment: What do you mean by you are interested in that string?

Comment: See update for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came back to this after starting to use rbenv. If you have rbenv installed, the following one-liner does the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts `~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv install --list`.split("\n").map{|item| item.strip}.select{|item| item[/^\d*\.\d*\.\d*/]}.reject{|item| (item.include? '-') && !(item =~ /-p\d*$/)}.last
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
curl 'http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/' | ruby ./extract-and-print-max-patchlevel.rb
```

Where the implementation of `extract-and-print-max-patchlevel.rb` script is an exercise for the reader but here's a start:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
maxpatch=0
maxstr=nil
STDIN.each_line do |line|
  next unless line =~ /1\.9\.3-p(\d+)\b/
  patch = $1.to_i
  if patch > maxpatch
    maxpatch = patch
    maxstr = $&
  end
end
puts maxstr
```

Note that it assumes Ruby 1.9.3 is the latest, so you might want to revisit that.

Comment: "it assumes Ruby 1.9.3 is the latest" -- Unfortunately, this defeats the purpose.

Comment: @user456584 I think that can be addressed with a few modifications of this script, leaving the main idea the same. I described my thoughts in an **UPD** to [my variant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14693560/693538) of maerics' answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `sed` or `awk`. For example:

```
curl "http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/" | sed -E 's/^.*"(ruby-)(1.9.3-p[0-9]+)(.*)".*$/\2/' | sed -e '/^1.*/!d' | sort | sed '$!d'
```

I'm not `sed` expert and here could be better solution but this line works.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing between @maerics' and @YevgeniyAnfilofyev's answers, I found the Ruby one more *authentic* and turned it into one-liner, **assuming that the list from curl is already sorted**, so we simply need the **last** line meeting the condition:

```
curl 'http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/' 2> /dev/null | ruby -e "puts STDIN.lines.map { |x| /1\.9\.3-p\d+\b/.match(x) }.compact.last[0]"
```

Or, Ruby part expanded:

```
puts STDIN.lines.map do |x|
  /1\.9\.3-p\d+\b/.match(x) # After such map we will get an array of MatchData or nils
end.compact.last[0] # Then we remove nils using Array#compact,
                    # get last MatchData and retrieve matched string with [0]
```

Following a good tradition, adding sorting to this script left as an excercise for the reader :)

**UPD:** Of course, hard-coded 1.9.3 is bad, but if we replace each digit 1, 9 and 3 with `\d`, the regex seems to become more or less independent. The other problem is that we only look into `.../ruby/1.9` folder of that ftp. This may be fixed if we, instead, look into `.../ruby` folder first, and find all version-numbered folders with regex `/\d\.\d\//`. Then repeat the above query, joining results from all folders. But, of course, this already cannot made into a one-liner...